# Bootstrap Glyphicon button font change.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

I have the code:

```
.pull-right= link_to content_tag(:i, Search, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"), '#', id: "searchit"
```

I want to change the font of " Search" to something other than Times New Roman, and I don't have a clue how to change it. [Here's what it looks like atm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqcPp.png)

I've looked at this quiet a bit, and I can't seem to figure out what do with the combination of haml & sass. Quiet new to this too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first put glyphicon first and then put text and style text by using the class. Something like this

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"><div class="searchtext">Search</div>
```

Then

```
  .searchtext{
           //put font css here
   }
```

Comment: That didn't work either. It changed the font, but disabled the chevron, which is what happens every time I find a way to change the font.